# django throws error: Invalid column name 'id' (SQL SERVER)

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I try to create a web app using django and connecting to a SQL Server Database. The table that I use to display the data in a django form consists of 2 columns. Both of them being a foreign key and both of them together building the primary key of the table

> CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable](     [ID_Field1] [int] NOT NULL,
>     [ID_Field2] [int] NOT NULL,  CONSTRAINT [PK_Movies2Genres] PRIMARY
>   KEY CLUSTERED  (  [ID_Field1] ASC,    [ID_Field2] ASC )WITH (PAD_INDEX =
>   OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,
>   ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY] ) ON
>   [PRIMARY]
>
> ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyTable]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Field2]
>   FOREIGN KEY([ID_Field2]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Table2] ([ID_Field2])
>
> ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyTable] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Field2]
>
> ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyTable]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Field1]
>   FOREIGN KEY([ID_Field1]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Table1] ([ID_Movie])
>
> ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyTable] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Field1]

Now, django apperantly cannot create a model corresponding to this kind of sql table structure, i.e. it cannot create a primary key consisting of more than one field. Instead, it sets the primary key on one of the 2 columns and in the meta section of the model class it sets

> unique_together = (('id_field1', 'id_field2'),)

The complete model:

> class MyTable(models.Model):
>
> ```
> id_field1 = models.ForeignKey(Table1, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='ID_Field1') 
> id_field2 = models.ForeignKey(Table2, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='ID_Field2')
>
> class Meta:
>     managed = False
>     db_table = 'MyTable'
>     unique_together = (('id_field1', 'id_field2'),)
> ```

However, this is what django inspectdb tells me to do. I know that django creates automatically a field called id when there is no primary key defined. This seems to be the case here, although there is a primary key defined. Any idea how to deal with that problem?

Answer (score 1):

use: https://github.com/onysos/django-composite-foreignkey

```
class Customer(models.Model):

    company = models.IntegerField()
    customer_id = models.IntegerField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    address = CompositeForeignKey(Address, on_delete=CASCADE, to_fields={
        "tiers_id": "customer_id",
        "company": LocalFieldValue("company"),
        "type_tiers": RawFieldValue("C")
    })

    class Meta(object):
        unique_together = [
            ("company", "customer_id"),
        ]


class Contact(models.Model):
    company_code = models.IntegerField()
    customer_code = models.IntegerField()
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    # virtual field
    customer = CompositeForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=CASCADE, related_name='contacts', to_fields={
        "customer_id": "customer_code",
        "company": "company_code"
    })
```

Comment: How would I define the CompositeForeignKey if customer_id is related to the model Customer and company would be related to a model Company? The CompositeForeignKey takes only one model as an argument, right?

Comment: I'm sorry i do not know! I'm having the same problem as you, and CompositeForeignKey was not the best solution for me, I left it parked and I'm erasing other fires in company. If you have news, please let me know!

Comment: My workaround was just adding another id field. I am not really happy with this solution but django doesn't seem to support this kind of model structure.

Answer (score 0):

Django adds the id column automatically if it doesn't find the Primary key column in the model.

In your case, simply add Primary key = True to one of the foreign key statement and it should work fine.